# XFCE- Small caps in Clock?

Tags: xfce, fonts, clock

I am trying to make the month and day in my clock in XFCE be in small caps, because I like the look. To be clear, this is what I mean:

[image: Example image]

The image above was achieved in LibreOffice using Linux Libertine O font, with `:smcp` added to the end of the name. Linux Libertine is my systemwide font. Upon doing some basic research, I discovered that Pango markup is supported in the "Custom Format" terminal in the "Clock" options. Reading into Pango, small caps should be easily achievable by writing:

`<span font-variant="smallcaps">*text here*</span>`

This does not work, it changes nothing. I also tried the attribute `font="Linux Libertine Display O:smcp"`, trying the same trick as in LibreOffice, this also did not work. Other Pango markup elements work fine like `<b>` and `<u>`, and other span attributes work perfectly, such as `font-style` and `font-weight`. The font clearly supports small caps, I was able to get that example image. I tried copying the unicode small uppercase letters from Wikipedia, but the font does not apply to them, and they stick out like a sore thumb. I am running XFCE 4.14 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

For further clarity, this is what my clock looks like now:

[image: Current]

This is how I would want it to look like (again, made in LibreOffice):

[image: Ideal]

It seems like this isn't something many people are trying to do, so I haven't been able to find any troubleshooting information online. If anyone has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check the package manager ... there may be a list of files that is used by the clock ... perhaps one of the files is the font file

Comment: looks like you are asking in the wrong place .... try at https://forum.xfce.org/ .... https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=13718 .... https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=54292#p54292

Comment: If the goal is to have _a_ clock with small caps rather than necessarily using _the_ Xfce clock, take a look at the Orage Panel Clock, which should be in your distro's repo. It's much more configurable, and the font can be selected from a dialog through its properties.